# C funcion pointer to specific address

Tags: c, function, pointers

Using GCC, I want to define a function pointer to a specific address, like this:

```
void (*fptr)(void) = 0x00400000;
```

Unsurprisingly, that throws a warning

```
Warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

I tried to cast the right-hand side like

```
void (*fptr)(void) = ((*)(void))0x00400000;
```

but that yields a syntax error.

How can I cast this correctly so that the warning will go away?

Comment: You forgot the return type in your cast (`void`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the return type in the cast. It should be:

```
void (*fptr)(void) = (void (*)(void)) 0x00400000;
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thanks.